# How to manage the nfs client after a nfs service restart?

Tags: linux, nfs

After a restart of the NFS service, how do I manage the clients?

All the clients I have do not have an NFS entry in the `/etc/fstab`, so I will not be able to do `mount -a` to refresh the connections. Could using `exportfs -v` be enough to restablish the connections ?

Answer (score 0):

It is save to restart NFA server. The clients will reestablish the mounts. Restarting NFS services on the client must be save as well, as this is limited to user space processes only, without unmounting. But check with OS.

Comment: Hi @Tigran, if I understood your response it is safe to restart the NFS service. I will run some tests and update the post later. Thanks